# Где в phpmyadmin просмотреть созданные ограничения с помощью check?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Где в **phpmyadmin** просмотреть созданные ограничения с помощью **check**?

Или есть команда которая выведет все существующие ограничения показывая с каким столбцом он связан?

Comment: [SHOW CREATE TABLE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/show-create-table.html) показывает полную и точную структуру таблицы. Включая и все имеющиеся ограничения.

Comment: @Akina Помогло. Спасибо!